# Spark cluster setup on windows servers - how to start master daemon process in background

Tags: windows, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I created spark standalone cluster on windows servers by manually starting the master and workers using spark class command. They are opened in command terminal window. When i close or logout, cluster setup is gone. How can I run these in the background processes using start and stop scripts like the launching scripts that are meant for UNIX and alike OS systems? Is it possible to keep them alive under some system account? Can the same be achieved through Mesos or Yarn cluster on Windows servers?

Comment: You could use windows scheduler to run the commands at start and logout

Comment: You should search the great Internet for running stand-alone Spark cluster as service on Windows. This is the cleanest approach. But then, this is a programming site and not a system administration one, so your question is off-topic.